# Different Spring @validated group validations for same nested objects

Tags: spring-boot, validation, nested, bean-validation

So this is the scenario, I want two objects of the same class nested within the same object to validate differently.

For example, I want something like this:

```
class PowerStation {
   @Validated(groups: MainSupply.class) // I want this to validate one way
   PowerSupply mainPowerSupply;

   @Validated(groups: BackupSupply.class) // I want this to validate another way
   PowerSupply backupPowerSupply;
}

class PowerSupply {
   @Min(value = 1000, groups = MainSupply.class)  // Main supply needs to have more power
   @Min(value = 500, groups = BackupSupply.class) // Backup supply not as much power needed, only for emergencies.
   int powerOutput;
}
```

Comment: if any looking for an answer please check similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332112/spring-jsr-303-validation-groups-on-nested-fields

Comment: At a glance, this looks promising, might take me a bit to reimplement the solution to see if it is working correctly for my scenario.